# Redirect domain to a directory on another domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have bought a domain and I want to redirect it to a directory on another subdomain.

Exemple: 
A user type www.firstweb.com in the URL bar and he has to be redirected to www.secondweb.com/directory/ but the URL shown has to be www.firstweb.com without iframe.

Other exemple:
www.firstweb.com/contact/ shows the content of www.secondweb.com/directory/contact.php but the URL shown has to be www.firstweb.com/contact/ even after the redirect.

Both domain and servers are hosted by the same company (OVH).

I don't know if it is understandable but I dont know how to figure it out.

Thanks a lot for your help.

J.ROX

Comment: A [reverse proxy](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) could do this. However, this is more of a web admin question than a programming question.  There's a lot to it to do it yourself, so it is a broad question.  If the link doesn't help, you may be better off buying this as a service online somewhere... If you actually try to set it up and have difficulty, superuser or serverfault would be good places to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by installing NGINX (http://nginx.org/) on the webserver. Then you can check from which base URL the user is coming from, and return the appropriate content. This is also possible with an Apache server using Virtual Domain Names.

Or you can setup your DNS correctly, this can be done by your domain provider.

Comment: Thanks Wessel,

The NGINX solution seems to be a bit complicated. Concerning the DNS setup, it will target the other server but not the directory right?

I am interesting in the Virtual Domain Names but how does it work? What can I have to do in the firstweb.com htaccess and in the htaccess located on secondweb.com ?